# Why do we return the status code and response in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm currently learning node.js and express, and I encountered this:

```
exports.checkBody = checkBody = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.price) {
    // Return statement is here
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: "Please add a name and price"
    })
  }
  next();
}
```

Why do I need to put the return statement here, because when I remove the return, it works exactly the same.

Here is the routes

```
router.post(tourController.checkBody, tourController.createTour);
```

Comment: So you are wondering why you would not check to see if input is valid and return an error if something is not set? return exits....

Comment: If you remove the `return` statement, how do you send the error message back to the client?

Comment: @Barmar: With `res.status(400).json(…)`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the `return` is so you don't execute `next()` if an error is detected.

The return value isn't important, because `res.status()` sends the response to the client. So this is actually just a shorthand for doing

```
exports.checkBody = checkBody = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.price) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: "Please add a name and price"
    });
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: Wow this helped me a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` is used for the effect of exiting the function in this case, not for usefully returning a value. It’s a shorter equivalent that some people prefer as a style choice over this:

```
res.status(400).json({
  status: "fail",
  message: "Please add a name and price"
})
return
```

If you remove the `return` entirely, `next()` will be called, and the next handler will run, which usually isn’t correct after you’ve already responded, and especially not in this case where the middleware being implemented is validation that’s supposed to *stop* the route from running when validation fails.

I personally prefer the more explicit separate `return` for the purposes of avoiding exactly this type of confusion, but it doesn’t come up as much anymore now that promises and async + await are available as options.

Answer (score 1):

Because `return` stops the execution of the function. If there is no return you send the response back but that doesnt mean that the function stops to execute.

Imagine you have some kind of auth middleware that checks if an user is valid and you either send an error back or you move to the next Middleware with `next()`

Now you dont use `return`. You get an response on the client that you got rejected but on the serverside the code still got executed. I hope you get what i mean. Its maybe not the best example but... Yea..